# Block based programming and access to GPIO on Raspberry Pi 3B

Tags: pi-3, gpio, scratch

We would like to use Scratch to access and control the GPIO of our Raspberry Pi 3B.  Scratch 3 offline does not work on the Pi 3B due to the limited 1GB memory: it sometimes starts but typically stalls quickly after that.  Scratch 2 is Flash based and because of this I am not able to make this work on Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye. (I did review [this installation method](https://github.com/Botspot/scratch2), but does not work)

Scratch online does have extensions for some hardware (like Makeymakey and Lego Boost) but does not suggest the Raspberry Pi GPIO extension.

Is there any way in which it's possible to access the GPIO of Raspberry Pi within Scratch online, or is there a lighter alternative block based language that can be used on the Raspberry Pi 3B to access and control its GPIO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

raspblocks.com seems to give an alternative to Scratch that would meet the requirement of controlling GPIO in block based language.

Note that this a block based language that generates Python code, which is a different experience from programming and controlling the GPIO directly in Scratch.  However I feel this is good approach and makes the resulting Python code easier to comprehend to novice programmers.

http://www.raspblocks.com/coding/demos/code/coding.html

Comment: Looks similar to ArduBlock for Arduino. Perhaps you could describe what you need with generic words in the question (e.g. graphical / drag-and-drop / visual / block-based programming), so that people who don't know what Scratch is have a chance to find your question.